# Significant Performance Decrease after CSS Selector Change

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I made a small change to some SASS selectors in a fairly complex web application and saw a dramatic performance decrease. When profiling a page using Chrome's timeline feature, instances of "Recalculate Styles" (reflowing the page after DOM manipulation I assume) changed from about 1ms to about 100ms and the elements affected count for these style recalculations changed from about 10 to about 1500.

What makes this selector change quite so evil? In the future, what should I be wary of so as to not make the same mistake again?

Original CSS (fast):

```
.button-group .button:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: -1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.button-group .button:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

Modified CSS (very slow):

```
.button-group > :not(:first-of-type) .button, .button-group > :not(:first-of-type).button {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.button-group > :not(:last-of-type) .button, .button-group > :not(:last-of-type).button {
  margin-right: -1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  Sass compiles slow -> Sass problem.  Browser renders CSS slow -> not a Sass problem.  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**.

Comment: Fair enough @cimmanon. But of course, that argument doesn't apply universally. "Scala compiles slow -> Scala problem. JVM runs bytecode slow -> not a Scala problem. Unless you have a Scala -> bytecode compilation issue, only post the compiled bytecode." Is there some sort of place this rule is documented, or is it one of those "unwritten SO rule" type of things?

Comment: The browser doesn't care how the CSS was generated.  Debugging problems require an [MCVE].  Unless Sass is actually part of the problem (ie. you can only reproduce the problem with Sass), than it isn't relevant  to the question being asked.

Comment: @cimmanon I would argue that making a MCVE doesn't prohibit using reasonable abstraction and/or syntax sugar. It seems to me that this choice in level of abstraction should be left up to the user. Nonetheless, in this case CSS is fine, and this is really a meta-level discussion

Comment: It is inconsiderate of you to expect users who might be able to help you to install/find a Sass compiler just to reproduce the problem (Sass experts typically understand CSS, but CSS experts cannot be expected to know Sass).  It is also inconsiderate of you to spam tags that aren't even related to the problem (Sass is not necessary for reproducing the problem).

Answer (score 0):

To break this down, I'm going to ignore the `.button-group` since it's the same in both and won't affect anything.

In the first example, you select every `button` class.  Browsers are optimized for searching for classes, so that's typically very fast.  You then use the `not(:last-of-type)` modifier, which is slower, but doesn't matter as much since the pool has already been limited to only the `button` class.

In the second example, you search for `:not(:first-of-type)` first, which performs the expensive operation on every child of `.button-group`.  While using the direct child operator (`>`) will help limit that pool, chances are it's still a greater number of elements than the first example.  I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with the `.button, &.button`, but either way that operation is not very costly since you're just selecting by class and you've already limited the pool quite a bit.

So in general, you want to go from least costly operation to most costly so that the intensive calculations are done on the smallest number of elements possible.

Side note, I think you're missing a comma after `.button` in your second example.

---

Edit: Just want to point out the difference that your two pieces of code compile to.

First:

```
.button-group .button:not(:last-of-type)
```

Second:

```
.button-group > :not(:first-of-type) .button, 
.button-group > :not(:first-of-type).button {
```

As you can see, the second has quite a bit more going on.  That alone could be the reason it's slower, though I'm checking now to make sure that the ordering of the `not` has an impact.

Comment: "In the second example, you search for :not(:first-of-type) first" Again, the `.button, &.button` selector nested underneath it means by the time the browser gets to the negation it's already looking at only `.button` elements and nothing else.

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't think that's true.  Have you looked at the compiled code?

Comment: @BoltClock, Yeah, I'm right here.  Compiled code is : `.button-group > :not(:first-of-type) .button, .button-group > :not(:first-of-type).button {`.  `:not` comes before `.button`, so that calculation is done first.  If it was reversed it would be faster.  Compare the two and let me know if you see something else.

Comment: Huh. Never would have thought the order of simple selectors actually mattered performance-wise. That seems like a flaw. But I'm not an implementer so what do I know...

Comment: That's what I learned, but I could be wrong... I'm actually really curious about this, I'll do some tests and make sure.

Comment: I don't think `.classA:not(:whatever)` performs differently than `:not(:whatever).classA`. AFAIK, these should be the same selector semantically and thus would be implemented in the same best way possible. (Not certain on this, but its logical.)

Comment: I added an edit to may answer.  Still checking on that `not` ordering, but the second example's compiled code is at least much more complex, which should add some overhead either way.

Comment: @RobertIngrum Agreed, the second selector set is more complex, but why it's 100x or more complex is a mystery! :)

Comment: @JKillian So I'm using this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cpg31oz7/) to try and test things, but I'm only getting a 3 - 5 ms difference between the two.  Is your html significantly complex that it would impact anything?  Maybe some js in the background?

Comment: The HTML is somewhat complex (full-scale, web application that would have been a desktop application 5 years ago type of thing)

Comment: @RobertIngrum My hunch is that the key difference is `:not(:first-of-type) .button` vs `:not(:first-of-type).button`. (Descendant instead of the same element.) But I don't understand why it would be such a significant difference.

Comment: I had a feeling it's because of the `not` search before the `.button` search.  I haven't been able to verify though because the difference in render time on my test is within 10ms.  The `not` search would select everything except the first of each type, which I assume is a greater number of elements than if you ran `.button`.  This would make further searches take longer (more elements).  Again, this isn't tested so I could be completely off base.